# Using Javascript/jQuery to find similar SELECT options

Tags: javascript, jquery, match

I'm currently using the .filter() method to match the value of an INPUT field (***prjName***) to an option in a `SELECT` field (***prjList***). This only works when the entered value is an exact match for the option text:

```
$("select[title='Projects List'] option").filter(function()
{
  return $(this).text() === prjName 
}).prop('selected', true);
```

So this code attempts to choose the first option in ***prjList*** that matches the text typed into ***prjName***. No problems there, working as expected.

I have a second SELECT field to the side, let's call it ***prjSimilar***. I can dynamically add options to ***prjSimilar***. No problems there. What I'm trying to do is - in addition to an exact match - find anything similar to the value of ***prjName***, then add it as a new option in ***prjSimilar***. Essentially a keyword search. For example, if the user types "RED VOLKSWAGEN BEETLE" into the text box, I want to find any option in ***prjList*** that contains one of those three words, adding each one to ***prjSimilar*** as it finds it.

So far I've tried variations of .filter() and indexOf but I'm not having any success.

**What Javascript/jQuery method can be used to find *similar* items in a list?**

Comment: You could use the `.split()` method to get an array of all the typed words. Then you could do a check between the first list and this array.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to find any option in prjList that contains one of those three words

Try to split names to words and compare to each other:

```
$("select[title='Projects List'] option").filter(function()
{  
   var words = $(this).text().split('');
   var prjWords = prjName.split('');

   for ( var i = 0; i < words.length; i++ ) {
     for ( var j = 0; j < prjWords.length; j++ )
       if ( words[i] == words[j] ) {
         return true;
       }
     }
   }
   return false;
}).prop('selected', true);
```